# Polymorphic views in ui-router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Let's say I have a `person` data object that can be different types of people:

```
{
  name: 'Clyde',
  gender: 'male'
},
{
  name: 'Jean',
  gender: 'female'
}
```

So, I have a view state that handles this for me, but I want the details within to be different...

**State**

```
$stateProvider.state('person', {
  url: '/person/:id',
  templateUrl: 'person.html',
  controller: 'PersonController',
  resolve: {
    personInstance: function($stateParams, dataModel) {
      return dataModel.getPerson($stateParams.id);
    }
  }
};
```

**View**
    Person: {{personInstance.name}}

Ok, so I have my state, but I want sub-states to represent my different polymorpic views:

```
$stateProvider
  .state('person.male', {
    templateUrl: 'person-male.html',
    controller: 'PersonMaleController'
  })
  .state('person.female', {
    templateUrl: 'person-female.html',
    controller: 'PersonFemaleController'
  });
```

Cool.  But... how do I transition to the state?  I don't know which type of person this is until the data resolves.  Do I need to do this in the `onEnter` callback of the parent sttae?

```
onEnter: function($state, $stateParams, personInstance) {
  if(personInstance.gender === 'male') {
    $state.go('person.male', $stateParams);
  } else if(personInstance.gender === 'female') {
    $state.go('person.female', $stateParams);
  }
}
```

This seems reasonable, but doing this triggers the parent state, which causes an `onEnter` event, which cause the transition, which will happen forever.  In general, this feels a bit off anyways, but I can't figure out a better way to do it.  It feels like there is a better way.

**edit**
By the way, I've tried keeping it as a single state and doing an `ng-switch` in the `person.html` and using `ng-include` to include the template, which explicitly sets the controller... but that child controller doesn't get the reference to `personInstance` passed in.  This feels worse than what I have anyways, but it is something I have tried.

Comment: should 'variable.male' be 'person.male'? And same for female?

Answer (score 0):

Your solution works nicely, except you have to do the redirect in `PersonController`, which is not inherited by the child states. It also seems quite appropriate to redirect from the parent controller, which can contain any logic common to all child types.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <script src="angular.js"></script>
    <script src="angular-ui-router.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Polymorphic States with ui-router</h1>
<div ui-view></div>

<script>

    var app = angular.module('app', ["ui.router"]);

    app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/person/1");
        $stateProvider
                .state('person', {
                    url: '/person/:id',
                    //templateUrl: 'person.html',
                    template: '<h2>Generic Person Template</h2><ui-view></ui-view>',
                    controller: 'PersonController',
                    resolve: {
                        personInstance: function($stateParams, dataModel) {
                            return dataModel.getPerson($stateParams.id);
                        }
                    }
                })
                .state('person.male', {
                    template: '<h3>This is a male person view</h3>',
                    controller: 'PersonMaleController'
                })
                .state('person.female', {
                    template: '<h3>This is a female person view</h3>',
                    controller: 'PersonFemaleController'
                })
        ;
    });
    app.controller('PersonController', function ($state, personInstance) {
        // Do stuff here relevant to both genders.

        if(personInstance.gender === 'male') {
            $state.go('person.male');
        } else if(personInstance.gender === 'female') {
            $state.go('person.female');
        }
    });

    app.controller('PersonMaleController', function ($state) {
    });
    app.controller('PersonFemaleController', function ($state) {
    });
    app.factory('dataModel', function($q){
        return{
            getPerson: getPerson
        };
        function getPerson(id){
            var people = [
                {
                    id: 1,
                    name: 'Clyde',
                    gender: 'male'
                },
                {
                    id: 2,
                    name: 'Jean',
                    gender: 'female'
                }];
            var person = {};
            for(var i = 0; i < people.length; i++){
                if (people[i].id == parseInt(id)) {
                    person = people[i];
                }
            }
            return $q.when(person);
        }
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```